# Regex works as grep, not with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, grep

I've compiled a regex (based on other posts) that matches multiple date formats perfectly when testing with grep in Text Wrangler, but when I put it into PHP and use it with preg_match it doesn't match anything.

Here is the regex:

```
/^(((?:0?[1-9]|1[012])|(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|([a-zA-Z]+))([.]?[-.\\/\s]))?(((?:0?[1-9]|1[012])|(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))([,]?[-.\\/\s]))?((?:20|19)[0-9]{2})$/
```

It should match (and does in Text Wrangler):

```
03/12/2000
4 4 2011
16 04 1985
11/11/1911
04.13.2013
May 12, 1912
July 13 2012
March 1999
2015
1944
```

It doesn't match:

```
2000 12 4
11/11/1111
40.13.2013
```

Is there something I'm missing that should be escaped or formatted differently for preg_match vs. grep

Comment: Can you show how you are using it with preg_match?

Comment: That's a pretty long regex. You can debug by splitting up it's parts and seeing when it breaks.

Comment: smerny - standard usage: if (preg_match($pattern,$myStr)) ...

Comment: Can you also tell us what operating system you are using? The default flavor of regex that grep uses can differ across systems.

Also, are any command line arguments being passed to the grep command within TextWrangler?

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.8, no command line arguments that I know of. Just stock Text Wrangler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "s" flag to make it 'dotall' match ( to include newlines)

```
preg_match('#THE_REGEX_PATTERN#is',$myStr,$matches);
```

Comment: I don't think I want the s modifier. I'm trying to use this to basically validate that user input is at least formatted as a date for a date field in a form. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

it is working on regex testing tool.

try it at

http://toolspot.org/regex_tester.php

Comment: It does seem to work there, not so much on the other testing tool I found. Let me test it again...

Comment: I think this may be a clue, the regex works fine with jQuery and with Javascript but not with PHP. Are there things in PHP regex that differ from Javascript/jQuery? I'm suspecting the \\/ pattern as the problem, but I'm not sure